# How do I override the constructor when extending Array class?

Tags: javascript, class, overriding

I want to create a class named `Matrix4` that extends `Float32Array`. I want to be able to override the `Float32Array` constructor with a constructor that creates an array of 16 elements (normally I would invoke `new Float32Array(16)`, but now I just want `new Matrix4`).

```
// This function should override the Float32Array constructor
// And create a Matrix4 object with the size of 16 elements
var Matrix4 = function() {
    Float32Array.call(this, 16);
};

Matrix4.prototype = new Float32Array;
```

The error I get from this code is:

`Constructor Float32Array requires 'new'`

Comment: Hmm... I don't get that error.  I get `[]`.  Is it possible that error is from somewhere else in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't extend built-in objects like `Array` or `Float32Array` using the old-fashioned pre-ES6 syntax. The only way to do it is with [a `class..extends` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Sub_classing_with_extends):

```
class Matrix4 extends Float32Array {
    constructor() {
        super(16);
    }
}

let matrix = new Matrix4;
console.log(matrix.length); // 16
```

Comment: I had no idea. I've been sticking to the old syntax but I guess it's time to adhere to the new... Thanks!

Comment: @Birger There are still times when it's better to use the old style. But this isn't one of them!

Comment: Do you mean Javascript classes in general, or just this particular class?